# Basic math subjects book recommendations

Tags: book-recommendation

I've been wondering about what are the best books to review some of the elementary math subjects. My choices are listed below:

**Real Analysis:** Introduction to Real Analysis, R.G. Bartle

**Multivariate Calculus:** Vector Calculus, J.E. Marsden

**Linear Algebra:** Linear Algebra and Its Applications, G. Strang

**Complex Analysis:** Basic Complex Analysis, J.E. Marsden

However, I'd like to hear other suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Serge Lang _Algebra_ is a very good book. It has almost 1000 pages, so it is very complete, but you can skip all the stuff you are not interested in. It would be my recommendation for linear algebra. For analysis of one and more variables, you can choose Thomas' book _Calculus_. It is thought for physicist and engineers and this is the reason why I think it is ''basic''.

Comment: Linear algebra by Hoffman Kunze

Comment: What Dog_69 suggests as a good textbook is really more useful to most as a reference book; it is rather terse which makes it difficult to understand if you’re not already at least somewhat acquainted with the subject.

Comment: As far as Complex analysis goes, depending on which side you want to go... I didn’t mind Brown/Churchill but really enjoyed the Stein/Shakarchi book (this latter duo has a series of four books that are quite good, in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undergradute Analysis by Serge Lang

Mathematical Analysis by Tom Apostol

Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin

Calculus Volumes I and II by Tom Apostol

Linear Algebra by Serge Lang

Linear Algebra with Applications by W. Keith Nicholson

Complex Analysis by Theodore W. Gamelin

Complex Analysis by Joseph Bak and Donald Newman

Answer (score 1):

*Visual Complex Analysis*, by Needham, is a wonderful book which helps gaining a lot of intuition on the subject (especially geometric and visual one).

Answer (score 0):

Introduction to Real Analysis by Robert Bartle

Multivariate Calculus by James Hurley

Differential Equations by Shepley Ross

Complex Fundamentals of Complex Analysis for Mathematics, Science And Engineering (2nd Edition)
by E. B. Saff (Author), A. D. Snider (Author)

Introduction to Linear Algebra (Gilbert Strang)